# There is a way in unity to take a photo from the device camera and store it in the app?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, save, gallery

i used unity to create some easy games and i know a bit about coding but i can't figure out how to make this.
i'm trying to create an app to sort thing in boxes, so i need the app to take a photo of an object and save in a "gallery" always in the app. Online i found just how to take and save photos in the gallery of the phone, thanks in advice to everyone who helps me!

Comment: What do you mean store in the app? You mean store on the device persistent storage, such that only your app can read the image? Or you mean save to the camera roll and then fetch those images so you can display them in your app?

Comment: i want the app to be able to take photos and display it in the app like in a scrollable grid, idk if it make sense

Answer (score 0):

In unity you can use ScreenCapture class to take a screenshot.

> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot.html

And by the app I think you mean Android or IOS application. In that case you can use UnityNativeGallery repository on GitHub.

> https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeGallery